# What is the negation of $p\to \sim q$?

Tags: propositional-calculus

I know that the negation of $p\to q$ is ~p V q but I can’t seem to figure out the effect $\sim q$ will have on the negation. Also is their a way to check if something is the negation of a statement?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! I'm sorry, but the negation of $p\to q$ is $p\wedge ({\sim}q)$ since $p\to q$ is  $({\sim}p)\vee q$.

Comment: The negation for $p\to q$ is $p\land\lnot q$.  So by substitution ...

Comment: Caution.  The negation of $p\to q$ is ${\sim (p}\to q)$ but it is not $({\sim p})\to q$.  Which did you mean when you wrote ${\sim p}\to q$?  So in the same way, the negation of $p \to \sim q$ is $\sim (p \to \sim q)$.

Comment: Whoops meant to write the negation as ~p V q

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

The definition of implication in propositional logic can be expressed with

\begin{equation}\tag{1}
p\rightarrow q~:=~(\sim p)\lor q
\end{equation}

By this definition, the negation of $p\rightarrow q$ is $p\land(\sim q)$. This means that the statement $p$ implies $q$, is false only when the antecedent or premise of the statement is true, and its consequent false.

Using the same definition, negation of the statement $p\rightarrow (\sim q)$ is

\begin{align}
\sim(p\rightarrow (\sim q))~~~&Start\\
\sim((\sim p)\lor (\sim q))~~~&Substitute~(1)\\
p\land q~~~&De~Morgan's~law
\end{align}

To check if any two statements in propositional logic are the negation of one another, it is sufficient to substitute all instances of implication with the first definition, then negate one, and apply [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) successively to it until one reduces to the other. If this is the case, then they are negations of one-another.